# UITest iOS waitForExistence returns false but element is visible

Tags: ios, xcuitest

I am a litte new in iOS UITest so apologises if something does not make sense.

I am trying to assert if a staticText is visible but it always returns false despite being shown.

The Screen looks like this:

[image]

The test function code looks like this:

```
func verifyBlockedAccountsEmptyState() {
    print(profileListScreen.app.navigationBars["Blocked Accounts"].waitForExistence(timeout: 5))
    print(profileListScreen.app.staticTexts.element.label)
    print(profileListScreen.app.staticTexts["No blocked accounts"].waitForExistence(timeout: 5))

    var elementLabels = [String]()
    for i in 0..<profileListScreen.app.staticTexts.count {
        elementLabels.append (profileListScreen.app.staticTexts.element(boundBy: i).label)
    }
    print("staticTexts -> ", elementLabels)
}
```

And the output:

```
true
12:25 PM
false
staticTexts ->  ["12:25 PM"]
```

Any idea?

Thank you

**EDIT**
If I try to record the XCUIElement I get the following error:

```
Timestamped Event Matching Error: Failed to find matching element
```

Comment: Is "No blocked accounts" a text label? As far as I know, staticTexts applies only to text labels.

Comment: @ReinhardMänner No blocked accounts is UILabel with NSAttributedText

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A problem may be caused by using the wrong element type.

You probably should add a breakpoint and inspect this screen with `lldb`.

Type `po print(app.debugDescription)` to print the whole hierarchy of elements and their actual types.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you should be assigning an AccessiblityId to part of the view you are interested in. You can see what's available in a given view by getting the container XCUIElement's debugDescription.